# Android ActionBarSherlock tabbed action bar with a mapview

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview, actionbarsherlock

I have 4 views, two of which contain mapviews. What I really want in the end is a tabbed navigation between these 4 views.

After some research, it seams like the best idea would be to use ActionBarSherlock and make each one of these views a "Fragment" inside a master "Main" Activity. This seams like a very easy to do thing but is causing me massive amounts of trouble (indeed, seams to be a pain for everyone from what I can find online).

First, my code.
**ActivityMain.java**

```
public class ActivityMain extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    static String CLASS_NAME = "ActivityMain";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "here");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        this.createMenu();
    }

    public void createMenu()
    {
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        this.getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab tab1 = getSupportActionBar()
                .newTab()
                .setText("First tab")
                .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FragmentOne>(this, FragmentOne.class));

        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab1);

        Tab tab2 = getSupportActionBar()
                .newTab()
                .setText("Second tab")
                .setTabListener(new MyTabListener<FragmentTwo>(this, FragmentTwo.class));

        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab2);
    }

    public class MyTabListener<T extends Fragment> implements TabListener
    {

        private ActivityMain mActivity;
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private Class<T> mClass;

        public MyTabListener(ActivityMain activity, Class<T> fragmentClass)
        {
            mActivity = activity;
            mClass = fragmentClass;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            if (mFragment == null)
            {
                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, null);
            }
            else
            {
                //ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.animationtest);
                ft.attach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            if (mFragment != null)
            {
                ft.detach(mFragment);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

FragmentOne loads just fine, no problems on that one. FragmentTwo is where the trouble begins. Here is the files:
**FragmentTwo.java**

```
package com.test;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentTwo extends SherlockFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("Test", "Two!");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and the corresponding layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapMapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.40"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="MY_KEY"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/refreshButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="refreshSightings"
            android:text="@string/A_MAP_REFRESH_BUTTON" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now of course this is giving me the error *Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView*

I have tried importing the https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps package and replacing the already existing android-support-v4 package but when I try to run my app, it dies with the error that it can't find the ActivityMain class.

First question, am I even going about this in the right way? Should I be using this 1 main activity and loading all the other things in Fragments?

Next, if I am doing this in a correct way, is there a *good* tutorial for how to get this to work in a decent way? I can't find anything online except for other people asking the same questions and a few tutorials that haven't worked for me.

Basically, how can I have tabbed navigation with 2 maps in 2 different tabs?

Comment: Are you using google map API V1 or V2 ?